# How to resize editor file tab in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor, tabs, resize, helios

I want to resize the file tab in the eclipse editor. 
At the top of each file there's a tab with the name of the file but in my system its height is huge.

Using : Helios Service Release 1

System : Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your system font settings in your OS control panel or equivalent. Are any of them set to unusually large size? Eclipse picks up up system font settings for use in its UI.

Comment: I've changed everything settiing in Ubuntu System->Preferences->Appearance->Fonts, all of them are using size 8 but the size of the file tabs are still huge.
I've noticed that it is not only the file tabs but also the other ones too (Outline,Package Explorer, etc ...)

Comment: Could you post a screen capture?

Comment: I am using ExtendedVSPresentation for eclipse with minimal theme. Screenshot [here](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/extendedvs_mini.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Restart eclipse and the new font size will register on your file tabs.